# CryptoExchange API (yobit.net) and CloudFlare protection

Tags: web-access

I want execute http-request to yobit.net. For example:

https://yobit.net/api/3/info

In the browser you must wait 5 second for reload page first time without cookies from yobit.net

In Mathematica:

```
URLExecute["https://yobit.net/api/3/info"]
```

Result of the request is:

> Please turn JavaScript on and reload the page. Checking your browser before accessing yobit.net. This process is automatic. Your browser will redirect to your requested content shortly. Please allow up to 5 seconds…
>   DDoS protection by Cloudflare
>   RayID:3e11cb819d1b422b

How can I get data from api of yobit.net using Mathematica? Can I turn on JS or use cookies from web-browser?

Comment: I have same problem. How can I cross cloudflare protection via php/curl?

Comment: That's not a solution to your question, but have you tried other exchange sites? Many have APIs.

Comment: @anderstood, of course, I already use other exchanges, but no one guarantees that protection will not appear on them

Comment: Do you manage to deal with the whole exchange procedure (get the data, analyse it, apply a strategy and place order) within Mathematica? It's something I'd like to try, using an exchange API but did not look into it too seriously yet. Advice welcome!

Comment: @anderstood, Yes, it is possible to do this in Mathematica

Comment: What website did you use? PS: I just tried `URLExecute["https://yobit.net/api/3/info"]` multiple times but there is no Cloudflare right now. Of course you never know when it can come back...

Comment: @anderstood, now I use binance.com API. Before this I used yobit. You are right. Periodically administration of yobit blocked bots with cloudflare when activity on the exchange become higher that normal

Comment: Are you using web sockets? You might be interested in [166571](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/166571/socketreadmessage-never-stops).

Comment: Did you look at [Control a Web Browser Programmatically](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/ControlAWebBrowserProgrammatically.html) ? (it's not a fast and direct solution, but will help you scrap sites including those that have protection)