# Using sockets to connect to a trading platform

Tags: data-acquisition, webservices, networking, real-time, socket

I'm trying to use Binance's API. The following works:

```
URLExecute[ <|"Scheme" -> "http", "Domain" -> "api.binance.com", 
                   "Method" -> "GET", "Path" -> "/api/v1/time"|>]
(* {"serverTime" -> 1519522573487} *)
```

but I would like to use the socket instead. I tried

```
socket = SocketConnect[{"api.binance.com", 443}]
WriteString[socket, "GET /api/v1/time"]
message = SocketReadMessage[socket]
```

but the last command never stops (even without the `WriteString`). I also tried replacing the first line with `socket = SocketConnect["stream.binance.com:9443"]`, see [binance doc](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/web-socket-streams.md), with the same result.

What is wrong and how can I connect to the socket to return, e.g., the server time or last orders?

Related: [26875](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26875/mathematica-tcp-socket-client-toward-trading-platform/27809#27809) but does not use *Mathematica*'s latest features and [165297](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/165295/socketconnect-not-connecting-to-web-socket-address/165297#165297).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try:

```
socket = SocketConnect[{"api.binance.com", 443}]
WriteString[socket, "GET /api/v1/time \n"]
message = SocketReadMessage[socket]
```

note the "\n" message returns a bytearray. Without the "\n" it hangs. I am not familiar with the binance API but just generally sometimes one or more carriage returns are necessary in HTTP headers.

```
ByteArrayToString[%]
```

Returns a 400 error page. I am assuming you are looking for a timestamp.

Comment: At least I get an error now... I also get a 400 Bad Request error with `WriteString[socket, "!ticker@arr\n"]` (even without `\n`) but the string comes from [the doc](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/web-socket-streams.md). And yes, I am looking for a timestamp or anything that shows that the connection with the socket is working, such as any live data from the website.

Comment: I would say an error shows that the connection or parts of it is working, The remainder maybe how to send proper header and payload to get back the proper response. I was only trying to get you past the hanging. The link you provide does not help much as I see no info on the time part of the api.

Comment: I see. There is another doc which is not dedicated to sockets, [that mentions time](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md) in section "check server time".

Comment: I am not sure that SocketConnect is setup to do secure communications or the handshake that is required for https.